# How to divide each column of pandas Dataframe by a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, divide

I have a pandas dataframe in which I want to divide each column by the same data series values for each row. Each column and the data series have the same length. The data series has only float numbers but some cells in the dataframe have NaNs.

I tried various things but somehow I cannot get it solved.

```
df = df.divide(data_series, axis=1)
```

Any suggestions? many thanks!

Comment: I think you should try groupby

Comment: just found it, axis = 0 solves it. Many thanks

Answer (score 17):

I found the solution: setting axis = 0 solves the issue.

```
df = df.divide(data_series, axis=0)
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Format your `Series` index with df columns

```
df.div(pd.Series([100,100,100],index=df.columns))
Out[132]: 
      A     B    id
0  0.01  0.02  0.01
1  0.02  0.03  0.01
2  0.04  0.00  0.03
3  0.05  0.06  0.01
4  0.08  0.09  0.03
5  0.09  0.07  0.03
```

Answer (score 1):

Given dataframe `df` and series `s`, you can also use `numpy`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df.values / s.values[:, None],
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```